# how to get rect bounds of imageview

Tags: android, events, imageview, motion, rect

I have scaled the image to fit the imageview, so now I want to get the rect of imageview so that I can make 1 count for every finger drag made only inside the imageview and not outside. What I have done can be seen below but it is not working because it isn't showing any detection when I drag my finger up and down in the imageview, if it did it should increment 1 for every drag but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Inside onCreate of the main activity:

```
redShape = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
scaleImage(redShape, 300);
```

Inside Motion Event, Action down:

```
  rect = new Rect(redShape.getLeft(),redShape.getTop(),redShape.getRight(),redShape.getBottom());
```

Inside Motion Event, Action move:

```
    if ((posY > redShape.getTop() || posY <redShape.getBottom()) && rect.contains(redShape.getLeft() + posX, redShape.getTop() + posY)){
```

Inside the above if statement I have some code that increments 1 for every drag made in a vertical motion (up and down).

EDIT:

This is what I've done but for some reason like before it still detects a drag in the area above the image.

In the onCreate of main activity:

```
     redShape = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);

     drawable2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_shape);
     int h = drawable2.getIntrinsicHeight(); 
     int w = drawable2.getIntrinsicWidth();  

     Matrix m = redShape.getImageMatrix();
     RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
     RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, redShape.getWidth(), redShape.getHeight());
     m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
     redShape.setImageMatrix(m);
```

EDIT 2:

```
 m = redShape.getImageMatrix();
```

Have the following code in either action down (oldX,oldY touch points) or move (posX,posY touch points):

```
 float[] touchPoint = new float[] {oldX, oldY};
 m.mapPoints(touchPoint);
```

Comment: you dont need to scale the `Bitmap`, `ImageView` draws your `Bitmap` so that it fits the `ImageView` depending on `scaleType`, also use `ImageView`'s `Matrix` to do mapping between view<->image points

Comment: Thank you, how do I use ImageView's matrix to do the mapping between the view and image points? Would it be ok if you provide some code please.

Comment: read the Matrix API,  in particular map* methods

Comment: Thank you, could you please check my edit and advise please on where I could be going wrong.

Comment: use getImageMatrix() then call mapPoints() with point (0, 0) and see the result of mapping,  that should clarify how Matrix works, you can also use mapRect()

Comment: Thank you, for the map points, should I get the x and y from the action down oldX, oldY or the x and y from the action move, the current positions which are posY and posX?

Comment: did you call mapPoints ?

Comment: See edit 2 for clarification.